# To create a pre-trained model for C#

Tags: machine-learning, .net

I created a model with machine learning. Using the library `Accord.NET`.
I would like to keep the pre-trained model in a file (not in the RAM memory) how this is possible?

Note: not necessary to create the model with `Accord.NET` could be with Python (TensorFlow, PyTorch, etc) but to use the pre-trained model from my desktop application in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site - great first question!

In your scenario (assuming I understand it correctly) you have a saved model in python right? So, what I would do is create a new API layer (written in python, using something like the Flask framework) and I would create API endpoints for your algorithmic functions (could be as simple as just 1 for your predict function).

From there, you could run that python script on a server and expose that API to the outside world and it will run/respond just like any other REST API service. At that point, it would be fairly trivial to write C# code to access the API (or any other language you want).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to :

1. Build and train the model in Python ([TensorFlow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow/))
2. Use [ml.net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet-get-started-tutorial/intro) Library to execute the model in .net CLR. See the
   [Docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ml-net-0-6-machine-learning-net/).